# Is non-identical not enough to be considered 'distinct' for kmeans centroids?

Tags: k-means, armadillo, centroid

I have an issue with kmeans clustering providing centroids. I saw the same problem already asked (
[K-means: Initial centers are not distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250899/k-means-initial-centers-are-not-distinct)), but the solution in that post is not working in my case.

I selected the centroids using `ClusterR::Kmeans_arma`. I confirmed that my centroids are not identical using `mgcv::uniquecombs`, but still got the `initial centers are not distinct` error.

```
> dim(t(dat))
[1] 13540 11553
> centroids = ClusterR::KMeans_arma(data = t(dat), centers = 561, 
                                    n_iter = 50, seed_mode = "random_subset",
                                    verbose = FALSE, CENTROIDS = NULL)
> dim(centroids)
[1]   561 11553
> x = mgcv::uniquecombs(centroids)
> dim(x)
[1]   561 11553
> res = kmeans(t(dat), centers = centroids, iter.max = 200)
Error in kmeans(t(dat), centers = centroids, iter.max = 200) : 
  initial centers are not distinct
```

Any suggestion to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the issue you've mentioned with the following data:

```
    cols = 13540
    rows = 11553

    set.seed(1)
    vec_dat = runif(rows * cols)

    dat = matrix(vec_dat, nrow = rows, ncol = cols)
    dim(dat)

    dat = t(dat)
    dim(dat)
```

There is no 'centers' parameter in the 'ClusterR::KMeans_arma()' function, therefore I've assumed you actually mean 'clusters',

```
centroids = ClusterR::KMeans_arma(data = dat, 
                                  clusters = 561,                
                                  n_iter = 50,
                                  seed_mode = "random_subset",
                                  verbose = TRUE, 
                                  CENTROIDS = NULL)

str(centroids)
dim(centroids)
```

The 'centroids' is a matrix of class "k-means clustering". If your intention is to come to the clusters then you can use,

```
clust = ClusterR::predict_KMeans(data = dat, 
                                 CENTROIDS = centroids, 
                                 threads = 6)
length(unique(clust))    # 561

class(centroids)   # "k-means clustering"
```

If you want to pass the 'centroids' to the base R 'kmeans' function you have to set the 'class' of the 'centroids' object to NULL and that because the base R 'kmeans' function uses internally the base R 'duplicated()' function (you can view this by using print(kmeans) in the R console) which does not recognize the 'centroids' object as a matrix or data.frame (it is an object of class "k-means clustering") and performs the checking column-wise rather than row-wise. Therefore, the following should work for your case,

```
class(centroids) = NULL

dups = duplicated(centroids)
sum(dups)                        # this should actually give 0

res = kmeans(dat, centers = centroids, iter.max = 200)
```

I've made a few adjustments to the "ClusterR::predict_KMeans()" and particularly I've added the "threads" parameter and a check for duplicates, therefore if you want to come to the clusters using multiple cores you have to install the package from Github using,

```
remotes::install_github('mlampros/ClusterR', 
                        upgrade = 'always', 
                        dependencies = TRUE, 
                        repos = 'https://cloud.r-project.org/')
```

The changes will take effect in the next version of the CRAN package which will be "1.2.2"

**UPDATE** regarding output and performance (based on your comment):

```
data(dietary_survey_IBS, package = 'ClusterR')

kmeans_arma = function(data) {

  km_cl = ClusterR::KMeans_arma(data, 
                                clusters = 2, 
                                n_iter = 10, 
                                seed_mode = "random_subset",
                                seed = 1)

  pred_cl = ClusterR::predict_KMeans(data = data,
                                     CENTROIDS = km_cl,
                                     threads = 1)

  return(pred_cl)
}

km_arma = kmeans_arma(data = dietary_survey_IBS)



km_algos = c("Hartigan-Wong", "Lloyd", "Forgy", "MacQueen")

for (algo in km_algos) {

  cat('base-kmeans-algo:', algo, '\n')

  km_base = kmeans(dietary_survey_IBS, 
                   centers = 2,
                   iter.max = 10,
                   nstart = 1,                     # can be set to 5 or 10 etc.
                   algorithm = algo)

  km_cl = as.vector(km_base$cluster)

  print(table(km_arma, km_cl))
  cat('--------------------------\n')
}


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(kmeans(dietary_survey_IBS, 
                                      centers = 2,
                                      iter.max = 10,
                                      nstart = 1,                     # can be set to 5 or 10 etc.
                                      algorithm = algo), kmeans_arma(data = dietary_survey_IBS), times = 100)
```

I don't see any significant difference in the output clusters between the 'base R kmeans' and the 'kmeans_arma' function for all available 'base R kmeans' algorithms (you can test it also for your own data sets). I am not sure which algorithm the 'armadillo' library uses internally and moreover the 'base R kmeans' includes the 'nstart' parameter (you can consult the documentation for more info). Regarding performance you won't see any substantial differences for small to medium data sets but due to the fact that the armadillo library uses OpenMP internally in case that your computer has more than 1 cores then for big data sets I think the 'ClusterR::KMeans_arma' function will return the 'centroids' faster.

Comment: One quick question, do you know any reference directly comparing the output/performance between `stats::kmeans` and `ClusterR::predict_KMeans`?

Comment: @Sehyun Oh, I updated the answer based on your comment.